# Removing Unwanted Lines in Flutter's SliverList within CustomScrollView

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-animation

**Hello,**

#### Setup:

I am trying to render a `SliverList` in a `CustomScrollView`. The list items are a different color than the background.

#### Problem:

I am getting strange `1px` lines between `SliverList` items, and these lines jump in and out as I scroll down. I have included example code and an example image. How can I remove these lines?

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks!

[image]

#### Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SliverListTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const SliverListTest({super.key});

  @override
  State<SliverListTest> createState() => _SliverListTestState();
}

class _SliverListTestState extends State<SliverListTest> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Sliver List Test',
          style: theme.textTheme.titleLarge?.apply(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.purple, // change your color here
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            PageNavigationManager().pop();
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.purple,
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
          child: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverList.separated(
                itemCount: 20,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  );
                },
                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 5,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Environment:

```
Flutter (Channel beta, 3.17.0-1.0.pre.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3693], locale en-CA)
    • Flutter version 3.17.0-1.0.pre.3 on channel beta at C:\Dev\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 12b47270b7 (7 days ago), 2023-11-27 17:21:11 -0600
    • Engine revision dff66925dc
    • Dart version 3.3.0 (build 3.3.0-91.0.dev)
    • DevTools version 2.29.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the `SliverList.separated` just use a `SliverList.builder` and remove the `separatorBuilder` property, and you are good to go.

Note: I am not exactly sure what causes these lines. From my observations, they occur from a height of 1 px to 5 px of the container. (tested on chrome)

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Sliver List Test',
          style: theme.textTheme.titleLarge?.apply(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.purple, // change your color here
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.purple,
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
          child: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverList.builder(
                itemCount: 20,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. I changed to ```SliverList.builder``` but the problem persists. (running on Android phone)

Comment: I have attached an example. There are no lines on an android (mi 9 lite), chrome or windows device.

Comment: Copied your code exactly and I still have the strange 1px lines. I'm using a One Plus 6 and an A53.

Comment: It could be related to the following issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14288

Comment: I think you are right. It's most likely an antialiasing issue.